# Angular - Data Returned But ng-repeat Not Displaying It

Tags: angularjs, angularjs-ng-repeat

I'm having an issue where although my Angular JS is returning data from my backend, I can't get ng-repeat to display it.  Here's my HTML file:

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html ng-app="docManager">
<head>
    <link rel="stylesheet" href="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.3.4/css/bootstrap.min.css">
    <link rel="stylesheet" href="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.3.4/css/bootstrap-theme.min.css">
    <script src="http://code.jquery.com/jquery-2.1.4.min.js"></script>
    <script src="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.3.4/js/bootstrap.min.js"></script>
    <script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/angularjs/1.3.14/angular.min.js"></script>
    <script src="app.js"></script>
</head>
<body ng-controller="DocManCtrl as docs">
    <div>
        <input placeholder="Search" type="text" ng-model="searchKey" />
    </div>
    <table class="table">
        <tr><th>Document ID</th><th>Filename</th><th>Category</th></tr>
    <tr ng-repeat="document in docs.documents | filter:searchKey">
        <td>{{document.id}}</td>
        <td>{{document.filename}}</td>
        <td>{{document.category}}</td>
    </tr>
</table>
<button ng-click="docs.add()">Add Document</button>
</body>
```

And here is my JS file:

```
var app = angular.module('docManager', []);
app.controller('DocManCtrl', DocManCtrl);

function DocManCtrl($http){
    $http.get('http://localhost:3000/documents').success(function(data){
    this.documents = data;
    console.log('Data retrieved.');
    }).error(function(){
    console.log('Error: could not GET documents');
    });
} 

DocManCtrl.prototype.add = function(){
console.log('Hello, world.');
};
```

I know my $http.get is working, because if I print out the contents of 'data' to the console, I see the data from my database.  Anybody know where my mistake is?

Thanks!
Bryan

Answer (score 4, accepted):

When you use `this` in your callback function it doesn't refer to your controller. So you'd have to do something like this:

```
function DocManCtrl($http) {
    var self = this;

    $http.get('http://localhost:3000/documents').success(function (data) {
        self.documents = data;
    });
}
```

Comment: Dang it...rookie mistake. :)  Thanks, Rob!

Comment: @rob I don't know if this is a bit off-topic but, would you mind about give a look to [link](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/30371104/angularjs-swiper-triggers-before-ng-repeat-loads-images-from-json) ? I got a problem and I think it's pretty close to this one.

Answer (score 1):

```
var app = angular.module('docManager', []);
app.controller('DocManCtrl', DocManCtrl);

function DocManCtrl($http){
    var vm = this;
    $http.get('http://localhost:3000/documents').success(function(data){
    vm.documents = data;
    console.log('Data retrieved.');
    }).error(function(){
    console.log('Error: could not GET documents');
    });
} 

DocManCtrl.prototype.add = function(){
console.log('Hello, world.');
};
```